# Form plugin handling non-200/301/302 responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm working with the jQuery Form Plugin. I have my servers send 200 responses on success, which trips the `success` listener perfectly fine. Per the standard, 301 and 302 and transparently redirected by the browser. However, when the server returns, say a 401, the Form Plugin just silently dies. How can I apply a listener to non-200 responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XHR will have the responseStatus in it - you can use the complete handler instead of 'success' and check that property of the xhr.

```
$.ajax({ // ...
        complete: function(xhr){
           if( xhr.responseStatus == 401 ) {
               alert( 'awww crap' );
           }
         }
      });
```

Comment: This seems to have worked formidably. I included `success: callback` with `complete: callback`. The complete even handler takes two arguments, the first being an XHR object (status available on `xhr.status`), the second being a string `"error"` or `"success"`.

Comment: If you need to, you can append to the global ajax events too; the details will be in how you're building your application.